# How to debug Rails app that crashes on Heroku, runs fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails app runs fine locally. However when I pushed it to Heroku, it suddenly gives me `Status 503` and I can't even go to the home page, which is a static page.

The odd thing is that the app successfully builds and deploys on Heroku. But when I try to go to my app, it says "Application error." The logs from running `heroku logs -tail` only tell me this:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 
host=flow-portal-rails.herokuapp.com 
request_id=3a4ff52c-9ff2-44b0-a701-038b74319bf9 
fwd="107.143.141.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 
bytes= protocol=https
```

I am using BUNDLER 2.0.1, my Gemfile is correct. I am not sure what is making my app suddenly behave like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is setting:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

in your `config/environments/development.rb`.

If you have `config.eager_load = false`, then you *might* have problems in your app that you don't see in `development` because the culprit code isn't getting accessed (and, therefore, loaded).

In Heroku `production`, in contrast, all your code is getting loaded and *might* be surfacing problems you don't see in `development`.

When loading your entire app in development, then you *might* see the same issues that you're encountering on Heroku.

Now, setting `config.eager_load = true` *might* cause you various slow-downs in development, so keep that in mind. I set `config.eager_load = true` in `development` all the time because I got tired of the kind of unexpected crashes you're describing.

Or, this might not help at all. You'll have to see.

Comment: I was being an idiot sandwich and forgot to put ```end``` statements after my if-elses... Free points for you!

Comment: Did this help? Or did you figure it out by other means?

Comment: I figured it out by other means before I saw your post (it was the forgotten ```end```)

Comment: A'ight. Well done! You should, however, keep in mind the `eager_load` bit. It can help when errors mysteriously show up on Heroku when everything is working fine in development.

Comment: Can I ask you a question? I am done with the Michael Hartl tutorial and I am now on my own. I created a button for the admin to update stuff about the users (there's a list of users the admin can see). But I'm not sure how to add this feature since it's already in a Rails route defined to JUST show users. But I added a button on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in migrations that you run all the migrations on server properly but on Heroku all the migrations are not run properly.

Now you have two options:-

1. Rollback all your migrations and then run one by one each migration and deploy it to the Heroku.
2. Just delete the existing app on Heroku and make a new app then just deploy all your code from GitHub

Hope it helps